# When I resize my browser, button moves on screen

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

When im resizing my browser my button is going everywhere on the page. Also on mobile it is not positioned as where it should. The other elements do.
Can you please help me?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">

            <div id="header-name">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="header-name-cell">
                            <a href="./index.html">
                                Nl-Darts
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Voor al uw dart nieuws!
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div id="content">

            <div id="landingpage-intro">

                <h2>I gotta piss</h2>
                <p>
                    Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear. Your cells react to bacteria and viruses differently than mine.
                    You don't get sick, I do. That's also clear. But for some reason, you and I react the exact same way to water.
                    We swallow it too fast, we choke. We get some in our lungs, we drown. However unreal it may seem,
                    we are connected, you and I. We're on the same curve, just on opposite ends.
               </p>

                <h2>No, motherfucker</h2>
                <p>
                    Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot.
                    Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.
                    Some pilots get picked and become television programs. Some don't, become nothing.
                    She starred in one of the ones that became nothing.
               </p>

            </div>

            <div id="landingpage-button"><a id="landingpage-link" href="http://www.google.com">Go to full website</a></div>

        </div>


        <div id="footer">

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background-image: url("../images/dart-wallpaper.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#content{
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 10%;

  width: 80%;
  min-height: 500px;
  height: auto;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color:white;

  border-radius: 10px;
}



#landingpage-button{
    width:290px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.7);

    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;

    position: inherit;
    left: 40%;
    top: 50px;

    border-radius:5px;
}
```

I tried multiple things like changing position relative/absolute and some various things but it still keeps moving.

Also does anyone have some more tips to think of when positioning elements?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's acting like that because you have the left property set to 40%. It will always try to be 40% from the left. Remove the:

```
position: inherit;
left: 40%;
top: 50px;
```

from the `#landingpage-button` and add:

```
margin: 50px auto 0; //50px from top, auto left-right and 0px to bottom
```

Do this if you want to put it in the center of it's container.
I've made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5d8oomr/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much this was the answer. I have to wait another 8 minutes to mark your answer. I will mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Florin's answer should work, but I would like to recommend using em instead of px. Em can be used as a relative unit of measurement.